# Circle-Line Sliding Collision (js)

Tags: javascript, line, game-physics, collision, geometry

I'm doing a video-game in pure javascript with the Html-Canvas.

I need to find new save x and y coordinates of a circle colliding with a line.

I already find out a easy way to tell if a circle is intersecting with a line , but then i cant figure out how to find the new circle position according to the direction of the circle and the friction of the line.

[screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GI0C.png)

So the collision detection is done and its working now the problem is the future position of the ball.

I am not looking for a bouncing physic , i am looking for a inelastic collision.

What i thinked was :

1. Ratio of angleOfStart + angleOfImpact (lets say the angle of the impact is 90° , that means I'm colliding at the line in a perpendicular way , and the angle of start is 0° that means i'm moving right , so x shouldnt be able to grow , but y can go up and down... I thought that by applying this report we could find a formula valid for all collision angles.
2. Following the direction of the segment collided with ( when i collide with a line i know bot point a and point b , then i can calculate the angle of this line , then i can force my circle to moove only in that direction , multiplying the initial speed - some friction).

Both of those idea in my mind works , but once implemented them in javascript seems works only sometimes...

Lets say i have an object segment collided :

```
segment = {
   a : {
         x : // some value,
         y : // some value
       },
   b : {
         x : // some value,
         y : // some value
       }
}

circle = {
    x: // value,
    y: // value,
    ray: // value
}

future_circle = {
    x: // x where user wants to go,
    y: // y where user wants to go,
    ray : // value
}
```

I know that **circle is not colliding with segment**.
But if i let the circle move becoming **"future circle" then they will collide**.

I need to **change future circle values so my circle doesnt stops** and doesnt go trought the line ... i need my circle mooves in line with the segment, taking care about friction.

I decided to open my mind to other solutions , that surely will work better than mines.
Any help is appreciated.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The bounce angle will be the incoming angle + 180 degrees. If you are colliding with a wall, the direction will be -1* the current direction.

Comment: I know , but i dont need a bounce angle...

Comment: This is now a math question, not a programming question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kME3XP_F6vU

Comment: I know how to , given two points ( a line ) find the angle , but i dont understand how this can help me to find out a solution for my problem...